# android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView how can I change the icon of unselected items instead of just the tint colour

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

First of all, if its duplicated please let me know because I cannot find it.

I m working with the **BottomNavigationView** with custom icons.

My problem is that, after selecting an item, when its unselected the icon changes its colour/tint rather than reverting to its initial state.

The problem is happening only with the message tab.

**This is the initial state** *(speech bubble is border only)*

[image: Initial stage]

**This is when its highlighted**

[image: Highlighted stage]

**This is the wrong one** *(speech bubble is now solid white but it should have a border only)*

[image: Wrong sate]

I try to access that views in the OnNavigationItemSelectedListener but I couldn't...any help will be a life saver ;)

This is the method

```
private val onNavigationItemSelected = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    var result = false
    when (it.itemId) {
        R.id.bottombarWalks -> {
            it.icon = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.walks_on,null)
            switchFragment(0, WalksFragment())
            result = true
        }
        R.id.bottombarMembership -> {
            it.icon = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.membership_on,null)
            switchFragment(1, TabFragment.newInstance("Membership tab"))
            result = true
        }
        R.id.bottombarHome -> {
            it.icon = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.home_on,null)
            switchFragment(2, HomeFragment())
            result = true
        }
        R.id.bottombarMessages -> {
            it.icon = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.messages_on,null)
            switchFragment(3, MessagesTabFragment())
            result = true
        }
        R.id.bottombarMore -> {
            it.icon = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.more_on,null)
            switchFragment(4, MoreFragment())
            result = true
        }
    }
    result
}
```

*Thanks in advance*

**@FrancislainyCampos solution**

This is the XML that define the bottomNavBar Tabs after applying the @FrancislainyCampos suggestion

[image: bottomBar_menu]

This is the selector that I added

[image: tab_selector]

With that solution the app is crashing trying to inflate the BottomNavBar with this log:

```java
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{uk.org.ramblers.walkreg/uk.org.ramblers.walkreg.ui.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
[...]
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[...]
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable uk.org.ramblers.walkreg:drawable/tab_selector with resource ID #0x7f0700ce
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/tab_selector.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0700ce
```

Did someone have another idea...I m happy to try whatever because I m out of ideas

Comment: Hi, do you have a XML file where you set the drawables for the selected and unselected states using selectors? That's usually how I control which icons to show for each scenario.

Comment: @FrancislainyCampos it didn't work. I added the selector I create in the question and updated the XML in the case is something wrong that I missed...thanks anyway!!!

Comment: what is drawable `tab_selector.xml`?

Comment: Do you have all your drawables inside `res/drawable` folder or did you create folders like `drawable-v21`?

Comment: Thanks @forpas all of them are into the drawable folder...to be precise they are in the **drawable-nodpi** folder

Comment: I would suggest to copy and paste them all inside `res/drawable` folder because of `Resources$NotFoundException`.

Comment: Maybe the code on this project I have may help? https://github.com/francislainy/MyGists/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/francislainy/gists

Comment: Also, have you tried using a different image asset just for testing so that you can check whether the error is coming from your code or the image itself? What happens if you use the messages image on another tab or for another state?

Comment: The issue is produce because in the change from selected to unselected instead of replacing the icon with the one defined on the xml, its changing its colour from yellow to white. If I put a different icon it would do the same...just change the colour of the icon(tint colour I think its called)

Answer (score 0):

That's what I have on [this](https://github.com/francislainy/MyGists) project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/orange" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

---

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
        android:id="@+id/tab_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/home_blue"
        android:title="@string/tab_home"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

<item
        android:id="@+id/tab_location"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_location"
        android:title="Location"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

<item
        android:id="@+id/tab_tic_tac_toe"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_tic_tac_toe"
        android:title="Tic Tac Toe"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

```
 private fun bottomBarNavigationView() {

    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(onNavigationItemSelectedListener)
    navigation.selectedItemId = R.id.tab_tic_tac_toe
}

private val onNavigationItemSelectedListener = object : OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.tab_home -> {
                displayView(FRAG_COUNTER)

                return true
            }

            R.id.tab_location -> {
                displayView(FRAG_LOCATION)

                return true
            }

            R.id.tab_tic_tac_toe -> {
                displayView(FRAG_TIC_TAC)

                return true
            }

        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing but the icons that you used are just changing its colour. What I need is to change the whole icon not just the colour...the message icon tab shown on the pictures of the question when is unselected are different